# Class component doesn't receive props every time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I've class component that get props from the above component.
On the class component I use that props to update the local state, and then I use the values inside the state for the `render()`.

But something very weird happened, when I debugging the state\props variable its seems that the class component doesn't get the props(got undefined).

This is the class that send the props:

```
const EditInstitute = props => {
    const { id  } = props.match.params;
    const [institute, setInstitute] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => { //act like componentDidMount
        getInstitutesById({id}).then((response) => {
            setInstitute(response)
        })
        // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, [])
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <div className="page-content">
                <Container fluid>
                    {/* Render Breadcrumbs */}
                    <Breadcrumbs title="StudentTracker" breadcrumbItem="ניהול מוסדות"/>
                    <Row>
                        <Col lg="12">
                            <Card>
                                <CardBody>
                                    {
                                        (institute.object !== null)
                                            ? (<InstituteForm institute={institute.object} />)
                                            : (<Alert color="danger">{institute.errorName}</Alert>)
                                    }
                                </CardBody>
                            </Card>
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                </Container>
            </div>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}

export default EditInstitute
```

`InstituteForm` component which get the props:

```
class InstituteForm extends React.Component {
    state = {
        id: (this.props.institute ? this.props.institute.id : ''),
        name: (this.props.institute ? this.props.institute.name : ''),
        contactName: (this.props.institute ? this.props.institute.contactName : ''),
        phoneNumber: (this.props.institute ? this.props.institute.phoneNumber : ''),
        city: (this.props.institute ? this.props.institute.city : ''),
        street: (this.props.institute ? this.props.institute.street : ''),
        number: (this.props.institute ? this.props.institute.number : ''),
        deleted: (this.props.institute ? this.props.institute.deleted : ''),
    }
    
    render() {
        console.log(this.state)
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <CardTitle className="h4">עריכת המוסד</CardTitle>
                <AvForm>
                    <Row className="mb-3">
                        <label
                            htmlFor="example-text-input"
                            className="col-md-2 col-form-label"
                        >
                            מזהה המוסד
                        </label>
                        <div className="col-md-10">
                            <AvField
                                name="id"
                                placeholder="מזהה"
                                type="text"
                                className="form-control"
                                disabled={true}
                                value={this.state.id}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </Row>
                    <Row className="mb-3">
                        <label
                            htmlFor="example-text-input"
                            className="col-md-2 col-form-label"
                        >
                            שם המוסד
                        </label>
                        <div className="col-md-10">
                            <AvField
                                name="name"
                                placeholder="שם המוסד"
                                type="text"
                                errorMessage="ערך חובה"
                                className="form-control"
                                validate={{required: {value: true}}}
                                id="validationCustom03"
                                value={this.state.name}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </Row>
                    <Row>
                        <Col md="2">
                            <div className="mb-4">
                                <label
                                    htmlFor="example-text-input"
                                    className="col-md-4 col-form-label"
                                >
                                    כתובת
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </Col>
                        <Col md="4">
                            <div className="mb-3">
                                <Label htmlFor="validationCustom03">עיר</Label>
                                <AvField
                                    name="city"
                                    placeholder="עיר"
                                    type="text"
                                    errorMessage="אנא הזן עיר תקינה"
                                    className="form-control"
                                    validate={{required: {value: true}}}
                                    id="validationCustom03"
                                    value={this.state.city}
                                />
                            </div>
                        </Col>
                        <Col md="4">
                            <div className="mb-3">
                                <Label htmlFor="validationCustom04">רחוב</Label>
                                <AvField
                                    name="street"
                                    placeholder="רחוב"
                                    type="text"
                                    errorMessage="אנא הזן רחוב תקין"
                                    className="form-control"
                                    validate={{required: {value: true}}}
                                    id="validationCustom04"
                                    value={this.state.street}
                                />
                            </div>
                        </Col>
                        <Col md="2">
                            <div className="mb-3">
                                <Label htmlFor="validationCustom05">מספר</Label>
                                <AvField
                                    name="number"
                                    placeholder="מספר"
                                    type="text"
                                    errorMessage="אנא הזן מספר תקין"
                                    className="form-control"
                                    validate={{required: {value: true}}}
                                    id="validationCustom05"
                                    value={this.state.number}
                                />
                            </div>
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                    <Row>
                        <Col md="2">
                            <div className="mb-4">
                                <label
                                    htmlFor="example-text-input"
                                    className="col-md-4 col-form-label"
                                >
                                    פרטי קשר
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </Col>
                        <Col md="5">
                            <div className="mb-2">
                                <Label htmlFor="validationCustom03">שם איש קשר</Label>
                                <AvField
                                    name="contactName"
                                    placeholder="איש קשר"
                                    type="text"
                                    errorMessage="ערך חובה"
                                    className="form-control"
                                    validate={{required: {value: true}}}
                                    id="validationCustom03"
                                    value={this.state.contactName}
                                />
                            </div>
                        </Col>
                        <Col md="5">
                            <div className="mb-3">
                                <Label htmlFor="validationCustom04">מספר טלפון</Label>
                                <AvField
                                    name="state"
                                    placeholder="מספר טלפון"
                                    type="text"
                                    errorMessage="אנא הזן מספר טלפון תקין"
                                    className="form-control"
                                    validate={{required: {value: true}}}
                                    id="validationCustom04"
                                    value={this.state.phoneNumber}
                                />
                            </div>
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                    <Row className="mb-3">
                        <label className="col-md-2 col-form-label">מצב תצוגה</label>
                        <div className="col-md-10">
                            <select className="form-control">
                                <option disabled={true}>מצב תצוגה</option>
                                <option>מוצג</option>
                                <option>לא מוצג</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </Row>
                    <Row className="mb-3">
                        <Button color="primary" type="submit">
                            עדכן מוסד
                        </Button>
                    </Row>
                </AvForm>
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}

export default InstituteForm
```

The state is updating only when the IDE(web storm) is refresh the code because of the changes.

I've upload an video(with constructor but the code above have the same results) to illustrate the problem more clearly:

https://streamable.com/lossng

Comment: The first component is not a class component! It's a functional component. Or you just made a typo?

Comment: try setting the props values to your state from `getderivedstatefromprops`
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops

Comment: @NitheshNarayanan https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68853567/getderivedstatefromprops-is-not-updating-the-state

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the props values to your state from `getderivedstatefromprops` [reactjs.org/docs/…](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops)

```
class InstituteForm extends React.Component {

   constructor(props) {
     super(props); 
     this.state = { }
   }

    static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
        if (add condition if needed) {
            return {
                id: nextProps.id,
                name: nextProps.name,
                contactName: nextProps.contactName,
                phoneNumber: nextProps.phoneNumber,
                city: nextProps.city,
                street: nextProps.street,
                number: nextProps.number,
                deleted: nextProps.deleted
            };
        }
        return null;
    }

   render() {
    console.log(this.state)
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <CardTitle className="h4">עריכת המוסד</CardTitle>
            <AvForm>
                <Row className="mb-3">
                    <label
                        htmlFor="example-text-input"
                        className="col-md-2 col-form-label"
                    >
                        מזהה המוסד
                    </label>
                    <div className="col-md-10">
                        <AvField
                            name="id"
                            placeholder="מזהה"
                            type="text"
                            className="form-control"
                            disabled={true}
                            value={this.state.id}
                        />
                    </div>
                </Row>
                <Row className="mb-3">
                    <label
                        htmlFor="example-text-input"
                        className="col-md-2 col-form-label"
                    >
                        שם המוסד
                    </label>
                    <div className="col-md-10">
                        <AvField
                            name="name"
                            placeholder="שם המוסד"
                            type="text"
                            errorMessage="ערך חובה"
                            className="form-control"
                            validate={{required: {value: true}}}
                            id="validationCustom03"
                            value={this.state.name}
                        />
                    </div>
                </Row>
                <Row>
                    <Col md="2">
                        <div className="mb-4">
                            <label
                                htmlFor="example-text-input"
                                className="col-md-4 col-form-label"
                            >
                                כתובת
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </Col>
                    <Col md="4">
                        <div className="mb-3">
                            <Label htmlFor="validationCustom03">עיר</Label>
                            <AvField
                                name="city"
                                placeholder="עיר"
                                type="text"
                                errorMessage="אנא הזן עיר תקינה"
                                className="form-control"
                                validate={{required: {value: true}}}
                                id="validationCustom03"
                                value={this.state.city}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </Col>
                    <Col md="4">
                        <div className="mb-3">
                            <Label htmlFor="validationCustom04">רחוב</Label>
                            <AvField
                                name="street"
                                placeholder="רחוב"
                                type="text"
                                errorMessage="אנא הזן רחוב תקין"
                                className="form-control"
                                validate={{required: {value: true}}}
                                id="validationCustom04"
                                value={this.state.street}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </Col>
                    <Col md="2">
                        <div className="mb-3">
                            <Label htmlFor="validationCustom05">מספר</Label>
                            <AvField
                                name="number"
                                placeholder="מספר"
                                type="text"
                                errorMessage="אנא הזן מספר תקין"
                                className="form-control"
                                validate={{required: {value: true}}}
                                id="validationCustom05"
                                value={this.state.number}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
                <Row>
                    <Col md="2">
                        <div className="mb-4">
                            <label
                                htmlFor="example-text-input"
                                className="col-md-4 col-form-label"
                            >
                                פרטי קשר
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </Col>
                    <Col md="5">
                        <div className="mb-2">
                            <Label htmlFor="validationCustom03">שם איש קשר</Label>
                            <AvField
                                name="contactName"
                                placeholder="איש קשר"
                                type="text"
                                errorMessage="ערך חובה"
                                className="form-control"
                                validate={{required: {value: true}}}
                                id="validationCustom03"
                                value={this.state.contactName}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </Col>
                    <Col md="5">
                        <div className="mb-3">
                            <Label htmlFor="validationCustom04">מספר טלפון</Label>
                            <AvField
                                name="state"
                                placeholder="מספר טלפון"
                                type="text"
                                errorMessage="אנא הזן מספר טלפון תקין"
                                className="form-control"
                                validate={{required: {value: true}}}
                                id="validationCustom04"
                                value={this.state.phoneNumber}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
                <Row className="mb-3">
                    <label className="col-md-2 col-form-label">מצב תצוגה</label>
                    <div className="col-md-10">
                        <select className="form-control">
                            <option disabled={true}>מצב תצוגה</option>
                            <option>מוצג</option>
                            <option>לא מוצג</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </Row>
                <Row className="mb-3">
                    <Button color="primary" type="submit">
                        עדכן מוסד
                    </Button>
                </Row>
            </AvForm>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

}

export default InstituteForm