# `getDerivedStateFromProps` is not updating the state

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to update the state of class component via props that sent from above component,
At first I've set an constructor that fetch the data from the props and place it in the state but that did not work because of the render() did not called.

So I've reed of the function `getDerivedStateFromProps` which called before render, But I don't know if I'm using it correct.

I'm send an prop as `institute` from above component and implement the `getDerivedStateFromProps()` like this:

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
            if (prevState.id !== nextProps.institute.id) { // need to update
                return {
                    id: nextProps.id,
                    name: nextProps.name,
                    contactName: nextProps.contactName,
                    phoneNumber: nextProps.phoneNumber,
                    city: nextProps.city,
                    street: nextProps.street,
                    number: nextProps.number,
                    deleted: nextProps.deleted
                };
            }
            console.log("null")
            return null;
        }
```

I've also set an initState values:

```
 state = {
            id: '',
            name: '',
            contactName: '',
            phoneNumber: '',
            city: '',
            street: '',
            number: '',
            deleted: '',
        }
```

`getDerivedStateFromProps` if statement is true but it's not updating the state at all.

I will appreciate any kind of help.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the entire code of this component